# How to remove the column name on the first row of a csv file, when you export from a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, export-to-csv

I have a `datatable` that sucessfuly exports into a csv file.

It goes like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = tabelaSISH1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                             Select(column => column.ColumnName);                    
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", columnNames));
foreach (DataRow row in tabelaSISH1.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText(xmlDialog1.FileName, sb.ToString());
```

But the problem is that the first line of the csv file, is always the columns name. I don't want that.

I've the following in hopes that the line with the columns names would be removed, but, obviously all that happened was removing the first line of the data table, and not the column names.

```
 tabelaSISH1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

And it failed.

```
for (int row = 1; row < tabelaSISH1.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = tabelaSISH1.Rows[row].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));
}
```

And it failed again, both remove the first line of the datatable, but not the column names on the csv file.

Hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're explicitly getting the column names and writing them to the `StringBuilder` that is then used to write the CSV file to disk.

Just remove these two lines:

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames =
    tabelaSISH1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);

sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", columnNames));
```